# How data bind in header part in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my main activity...
i have three layouts..

```
<!-- Include Action Bar -->
<include layout="@layout/actionbar_layout" />

<!-- Include Fragmented dashboard -->
<include layout="@layout/fragment_layout" />

<!-- Include Footer -->
<include layout="@layout/footer_layout" />
```

actionbar layout is for header part
fragment layout for main functionality

i am unable to update the action bar layout feilds.
Please Help to get out of this.
Thanks In advance.

Comment: Is this actionbar_layout for action bar of app ?

Comment: No its just a layout file

Comment: How you are updating this layount? Is it dynamic updation?Can you paste you actionbar_layout here?

Comment: Please add you layout files here.